# How to loop over the column names and each rows in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, class

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'PC1' : [0.035182, 0.001649, -0.080456, 0.056460, 0.017737, -0.005615, 0.033691, 0.547145, -0.022938, -0.059511], 
    'PC2': [0.034898, 0.001629, -0.083374, 0.053976, 0.017603,-0.005902, 0.006798, 0.250167, -0.137955, -0.313852], 
    'PC3': [0.032212, 0.001591, -0.067145, 0.047500, 0.015782, -0.003079, 0.012376, 0.302485, -0.063795, -0.124957], 
    'PC4' : [-0.000632,0.001268,0.063346,-0.026841,-0.009790,0.029897,-0.018870,-0.449655,0.081417,-0.327028], 
    'PC5' : [0.020340,0.001734,-0.050830,0.008507,0.007470,0.013534,0.100008,1.083280,0.298315,0.736401], 
    'PC6' : [0.027012,0.001507,-0.036496,0.032256,0.012207,0.005451,0.081582,0.959821,0.337683,0.758737], 
    'PC7' : [0.027903,0.001625,-0.041970,0.039854,0.014676,0.002364,0.045583,0.620938,0.116647,0.214294], 
    'PC8' : [0.013828,-0.015836,-0.117484,-0.208933,-0.162090,-0.190467,-0.075784,-0.481607,-0.213148,-0.401169], 
    'PC9' : [0.009378,0.002712,-0.148531,0.040901,0.011923,-0.000078,-0.055367,-0.661758,0.242363,-0.392438], 
    'PC10' : [-0.002740,-0.000234,0.060118,0.027855,0.016309,0.009850,-0.108481,-1.560047,0.198750,-0.793165], 
    'PC11' : [-2.876278,-0.437754,0.764775,-0.627843,0.391284,0.090675,-0.007820,0.342359,0.052004,-0.200808], 
    'PC12' : [-2.411929,-0.414697,0.415683,-0.426348,0.302643,-0.160550,-0.051552,1.086344,-0.275267,1.219304]
})

df.head()
```

I applied a function 'pd.cut' to each column in the dataframe. qcut basically is Quantile-based discretization function.

```
cuts = []

for col in df.columns:
    cuts.append(pd.qcut(df[col], 2, labels=None, retbins=False, precision=3, duplicates='raise'))

X = pd.concat(cuts, axis=1)
```

Then, I want to take only 2 values that are unique from each column `PC1, PC2,..... PCn.`

```
uniq = []
for i in x.columns:
    uniq.append(x[i].unique())

unique = pd.DataFrame(uniq)
unique
```

The result look like this:

[image]

Unique variable consists 2 values in the form of **(a,b]**

Then I want to customize transformer class to create new categorical dummy features.

```
# custom transformer class to create new categorical dummy features
class WoE_Binning(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, X): # no *args or *kargs
        self.X = X
    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        return self #nothing else to do
    def transform(self, X):
      
        X_new['PC1:0.00969 - 0.547'] = np.where((X['PC1'] > 0.00969) & (X['PC1'] <= 0.547), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC1:-0.0815 - 0.00969'] = np.where((X['PC1'] > 0.0815 ) & (X['PC1'] <= 0.00969), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC2:0.00421 - 0.25'] = np.where((X['PC2'] > 0.00421) & (X['PC2'] <= 0.25), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC2:-0.315 - 0.00421'] = np.where((X['PC2'] > 0.315) & (X['PC2'] <= 0.00421), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC3:0.00698 - 0.302'] = np.where((X['PC3'] > 7.071) & (X['PC3'] <= 10.374), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC3:-0.126 - 0.00698'] = np.where((X['PC3'] > 10.374) & (X['PC3'] <= 13.676), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC4:-0.00521 - 0.0814'] = np.where((X['PC4'] > 7.071) & (X['PC4'] <= 10.374), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC4:-0.451 - -0.00521'] = np.where((X['PC4'] > 10.374) & (X['PC4'] <= 13.676), 1, 0)        
        X_new['PC5:0.0169 - 1.083'] = np.where((X['PC5'] > 7.071) & (X['PC5'] <= 10.374), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC5:-0.0518 - 0.0169'] = np.where((X['PC5'] > 10.374) & (X['PC5'] <= 13.676), 1, 0)        
        X_new['PC6:-0.0375 - 0.0296'] = np.where((X['PC6'] > 7.071) & (X['PC6'] <= 10.374), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC6:0.0296 - 0.96'] = np.where((X['PC6'] > 10.374) & (X['PC6'] <= 13.676), 1, 0)       
        X_new['PC7:0.0296 - 0.96'] = np.where((X['PC7'] > 7.071) & (X['PC7'] <= 10.374), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC7:-0.043000000000000003 - 0.0339'] = np.where((X['PC7'] > 10.374) & (X['PC7'] <= 13.676), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC8:-0.176 - 0.0138'] = np.where((X['PC8'] > 7.071) & (X['PC8'] <= 10.374), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC8:-0.483 - -0.176'] = np.where((X['PC8'] > 10.374) & (X['PC8'] <= 13.676), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC9:0.00132 - 0.242'] = np.where((X['PC9'] > 7.071) & (X['PC9'] <= 10.374), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC9:-0.663 - 0.00132'] = np.where((X['PC9'] > 10.374) & (X['PC9'] <= 13.676), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC10:-1.561 - 0.00481'] = np.where((X['PC10'] > 7.071) & (X['PC10'] <= 10.374), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC10:0.00481 - 0.199'] = np.where((X['PC10'] > 10.374) & (X['PC10'] <= 13.676), 1, 0)        
        X_new['PC11:-2.877 - 0.0221'] = np.where((X['PC11'] > 7.071) & (X['PC11'] <= 10.374), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC11:0.0221 - 0.765'] = np.where((X['PC11'] > 10.374) & (X['PC11'] <= 13.676), 1, 0)        
        X_new['PC12:-2.413 - -0.106'] = np.where((X['PC12'] > 7.071) & (X['PC12'] <= 10.374), 1, 0)
        X_new['PC12:-0.106 - 1.219'] = np.where((X['PC12'] > 10.374) & (X['PC12'] <= 13.676), 1, 0)              
        X_new.drop(columns = ref_categories, inplace = True)
        return X_new
```

Is there any faster and simple way to input (a,b] in unique variable and slice column name of X (PC1, PC2, ...PCn) into :

```
X_new['PC12:-0.106 - 1.219'] = np.where((X['PC12'] > a ) & (X['PC12'] <= b ), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for making a new post! You do not need to pass `X` to `transform` as X should already exist as `self.X`, and if it is meant to be different, you should rename it to make that clear. Also, what is `X_new` meant to be? It would help if you explain the intended output. The values in `X` are `(a,b]`, but you compare it to a single value? Do you mean to be making these columns in `df` and not `X`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the dataframes `df` and `unique` you could do

```
X_new = pd.concat(
    (
        ((interval.left < df[col]) & (df[col] <= interval.right))
            .rename(f"{col}: {interval.left} - {interval.right}")
        for i, col in enumerate(df.columns) for interval in unique.iloc[:, i]
    ),
    axis=1
).astype(int)
```

or

```
X_new = pd.concat(
    (
        pd.cut(df[col], [interval.left, interval.right])
          .rename(f"{col}: {interval.left} - {interval.right}")
        for i, col in enumerate(df.columns) for interval in unique.iloc[:, i]
    ),
    axis=1
).notna().astype(int)
```

Result:

```
   PC1: 0.00969 - 0.547  ...  PC12: -0.106 - 1.219
0                     1  ...                     0
1                     0  ...                     0
2                     0  ...                     1
3                     1  ...                     0
4                     1  ...                     1
5                     0  ...                     0
6                     1  ...                     1
7                     0  ...                     1
8                     0  ...                     0
9                     0  ...                     0

[10 rows x 24 columns]
```

Or build `unique` with column names either this way

```
unique = pd.concat(
    (pd.DataFrame(X[col].unique(), columns=[col]) for col in X.columns),
    axis=1
)
```

or, if you don't need `X`, this way

```
unique = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        col: pd.qcut(
            df[col], 2, labels=None, retbins=False, precision=3, duplicates='raise'
        ).unique()
        for col in df.columns
    }
)
```

and then do

```
X_new = pd.concat(
    (
        ((interval.left < df[col]) & (df[col] <= interval.right))
            .rename(f"{col}: {interval.left} - {interval.right}")
        for col in unique.columns for interval in unique[col]
    ),
    axis=1
).astype(int)
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps me to loop lots of values in my dataframe. I appreciate you doing this. I know Python is powerful in data processing.